# Installation error of jenkins in linux

Tags: linux, jenkins

Error as below while installing jenkins:

Setting up jenkins (2.79) ...

Job for jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See `systemctl status jenkins.service` and `journalctl -xe` for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript jenkins, action "start" failed.

> dpkg: error processing package jenkins (--configure):
>    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>    jenkins
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my Ubuntu 22.04. It turns out that Jenkins works well with only OpenJDK (11, 8) distribution of Java and not with other distributions like BellSoft JDK 19 which I had installed.

Install OpenJDK 11 (or 8) using the command sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre or set the default Java version to JDK 11 (or 8) using the command sudo update-alternatives --config java if you have other distributions of Java installed already.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Used
```$ java -version
      openjdk version "11.0.21" 2023-10-17
      OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.21+9-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04)
      OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.21+9-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Take care that port 8080 is not in use. If not edit `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/jenkins.service` and do `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and then `sudo systemctl start jenkins`.